# Parse.Cloud.httpRequest with duplicated parameter key

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, cloud

Hi I am trying to use Cloud.Parse.httpRequest to send http GET request, however the request has a duplicated key in its parameter, for example
www.example.com?param=one&param=two

I am wondering how can I achive it by providing a dictionary as parameter for params, I tried following but didn't work

```
var param = {param : ('one', 'two')};
// Neither do var param = {param : ['one', 'two']);
Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
    url: my_url,
    params : param,
    method: 'GET',
    header:{
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    success: function(httpResponse){
     console.log(httpResponse.text);
    }
  }
```

Wondering if this can be achieved without using string as params value?

Answer (score 0):

A simple look at the [excellent parse docs](https://parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide#networking-query) shows me that this is extemely easy. Please look at the provided documentation before asking a question.

```
Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
    url: 'http://www.google.com/search',
    params: 'q=Sean Plott',
    success: function(httpResponse) {
        console.log(httpResponse.text);
    },
    error: function(httpResponse) {
        console.error('Request failed with response code ' + httpResponse.status);
    }
});
```

With this you can pass in duplicate params I believe.

Comment: The solution I am using now is to construct a parameters as a string 'param=one&param=two' as pass in as params, wondering if solving it using JSON object as parameter is possible?

Comment: POST is more convenient to pass some JSON